# Custom password encrypted file system for storing files in Android

Tags: java, android, file, filesystems

is it possible to create a custom file system or use an existing file system like  [EncFs](http://www.arg0.net/encfs) to read data inside Android environment.

My idea is to make a virtual filesystem for storing some media files and developing an app which can directly access those files from the filesystem volume.

I hope im clear with my question.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need a rooted devices to use it. Or, you need to build your own firmware. Here's one, it's open source: http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/LUKSManager